# SwiftUI views in VStack are overlapping each other

Tags: swiftui

I have two views in a VStack. All looks fine until I try to enlarge the font in accessibility setting. Then for some reason the stack is not expanding to accommodate both views. Instead it is pushing one view on top of another. See below.
[image]

How can I align these correctly? Below is my code.

```
 var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .padding()

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image("tmp")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.88)

                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, alignment: .leading)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, alignment: .leading)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, alignment: .leading)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.white)
                )
            }
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .scaledToFit()
        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10, x: 5, y: 5)
        .scaledToFill()

        Spacer()
    }
    .background(Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.gray)
        .scaledToFill())
}
```

Comment: You can  remove the first ` .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` where is the top text

Comment: Why don't you give them paddings instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Issue:

The issue of overlapping is with this section:

```
    .scaledToFit() // Not needed
    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10, x: 5, y: 5)
    .scaledToFill() // Not needed
```

---

## The Answer:

You don't need neither `scaledToFit` nor `scaledToFill` there.

---

## Visualizing the Issue:

#### using `scaledToFill`:

[image: scaledToFill]

#### using `scaledToFit`:

[image: scaledToFit]

See blue borders? Thats the issue.

---

#### Some Tips:

1. There is no need to create a dummy Rectangle for background color. `.background` modifier can accept a color directly like:

```
.background(Color.gray)
```

2. You can *ignore safe area* only for `background` modifier like:

```
.background(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
```

3. Don't repeat modifiers! group them together and apply once like:

```
Group {
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
}
.frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.8, alignment: .leading)
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

4. Multiplying width in a float number can cause `misaligned` images. So always round the result like:

```
(geometry.size.width * 0.88).rounded(.down)
```

---

## Result:

#### Image:

[image: Result]

#### Refactored Code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.")
            .padding()

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Image("tmp")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: (geometry.size.width * 0.88).rounded(.down))

                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
                        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
                        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit")
                }
                .frame(width: (geometry.size.width * 0.8).rounded(.down), alignment: .leading)

                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
            }
            .cornerRadius(10)
        }
        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 10, x: 5, y: 5)
        Spacer()
    }
    .background(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I did cleanup my code as per your recommendation. But unfortunately the issue is not resolved. The image now disappears. I forgot to mention that this happens when I enlarge the font. I'm updating my question.

Comment: That's because the screen is not large enough to fit all content. then you should think again about how you want to show your `view`s in that case. Maybe using a `ScrollView` is a good option but using `ScrollView` is a little bit tricky and you may want to get rid of the `GeometryView` and use `padding` instead.

Comment: That did it!! I got rid of GeometryReader and added a ScrollView and it now renders fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the modifiers on the image to the following.

```swift
Image("tmp")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width * 0.88)
```

Comment: When I did that the image totally disappeared.